# Send two messages onConnected to Android wear using messageAPI

Tags: android, wear-os

Let me try and articulate my question. Using MessageAPI, I am trying to send a message to Android wear. However, I am making it send two messages (sendNote and sendUserNote)simultaneously when onConnected. Here is a snippet of the code. The whole code is all over the place but this should be useful. The problem is that my onMessage received call doesn't get called when I call the two functions onConntected. However, when I just have only one sendMessage function inside onConnected, the onMessageReceived in wear listener service is getting called. Is calling two messages a real problem in this case?

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG,"INSIDE ONCONNECTED",mContext);
    Log.i(TAG, "Sending trigger for alarm to watch", mContext);
    WearNoteSender.sendNote("trigger",mContext);
    WearNoteSender.sendUserNote(UserManager.getUserEmail(), mContext);
    stopSelf();
}
```

Comment: The source of your `WearNoteSender.send*` methods might be helpful.

Comment: Hey thanks! I found the bug. I had initialized my sharedPrefs at the wrong place.